# How to restrict the pawn ♟️ movement in a chess board?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, chess

*Please don't get aghast of TypeScript. It's just js with types.*

I'm making a chess game and I've reached the part of validating the movements. My Tile class is as follows:

```
class Tile {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  tile: Element;
  team: string;
  piece: string;
  constructor(i: number, j: number, tile: Element, team: string) {
    this.x = i;
    this.y = j;
    this.tile = tile;
    this.piece = "none";
    this.team = team;
  }
}
```

As you can see I have control of the x and y position of any given tile in my 2D array.

I have the following function that returns an array with the total movement that each piece has made in its y and x coordinates. It receives 2 `Tile` objects as parameters. The first one is the initial click, and the last one is the ending click (where the user wants to move the piece).

```
function getVectorComponents(start: Tile, end: Tile) {
  return [Math.abs(start.x - end.x), Math.abs(start.y - end.y)];
  //getVectorComponents(start_position, end_position)[0] returns the movement in the y axis
  //getVectorComponents(start_position, end_position)[1] returns the movement in the x axis
}
```

I have managed to validate the movement of the rook ♜ with the following:

```
  if (
    (getVectorComponents(start, end)[0] <= 7 &&
      getVectorComponents(start, end)[1] == 0) ||
    (getVectorComponents(start, end)[0] == 0 &&
      getVectorComponents(start, end)[1] <= 7)
  ) {
    //This is an available move for the rook
  }
```

My problem comes when I try to validate the movement of a pawn ♟️. Since my `getVectorComponents()` returns the absolute value of the movement, I don't know the direction of this movement.

I have the following validation algorithm for the pawn:

```
  if (start.x == 6 || start.x == 1) {
    //Check if the pawn hasn't moved, if not: it has 2 available moves
    if (
      getVectorComponents(start, end)[0] <= 2 &&
      getVectorComponents(start, end)[1] == 0
    ) {
      //This is an available move for the pawn
    }
  } else {
    //The pawn only has 1 move available
    if (
      getVectorComponents(start, end)[0] <= 1 &&
      getVectorComponents(start, end)[1] == 0
    ) {
      //This is an available move for the pawn
    }
  }
```

This algorithm leads to the following problem:
[image: Pawn available moves]

**In a chess game, the pawn can't move backwards.** But, the algorithm that I have returns this movement as valid.

Is there a nice way to restrict the movement of the pawns, so that they can only move forwards? This needs to take into consideration the white and black team.

> More information: `a8 = [0][0]` `h1 = [7][7]`

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you determine if castling is possible, your algorithm does not have enough information. And your statement "The pawn only has 1 move available" is wrong since 'en passant' taking may be an option, to determine that the algorithm once again needs a lot more information.

Comment: As you noticed yourself, I believe you need a "direction" concept. Maybe this could be added to the "team" property, e.g. instead of `team: string`, you would get a `team: Team` that would hold a `direction` property somehow (e.g. `UP` or `DOWN`, or even `1` and `-1` which might simplify the calculations down the route). The key is that the authorised movements from a tile depend on the owner of that tile, which makes me think `string` isn't expressive enough.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but you may want to consider running `getVectorComponents` once and storing the result in a variable. It probably doesn't make much of a difference right now with the simple calculation, but generally, you don't want to run something that gives you the same answer multiple times if you don't have to (DRY).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend in your check for valid moves, check that, if the pawn is one color, start.x must be greater than end.x, and vice versa for the other color. I.e
White can only move when end.x is greater, black can only move when start.x is greater. It seems like you're laser focused on the vector components. You can use simple comparisons of the original values as well!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It worked but this result's in a lot of nested if's. Maybe i'm the one over complicating the task. But im looking forward for a more clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function getVectorComponents(start: Tile, end: Tile) {
  return [end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y];
}
```

This way you preserve the direction and can check later, when moving a pawn, if the direction is negative. If it is negative, you know that the move is invalid.